# Cronjob fails to renew letsencrypt certs

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, cron, lets-encrypt

I use letsencrypt for a Parse server I am running, and I have set a cronjob to renew every month, to ensure the certs never expire.

The issue is, the crontab does not seem to run correctly. Yet, it is the same command I use to run it.

```
@monthly root home/itsmemario/certbot-auto renew --pre-hook "service nginx stop" --quiet --no-self-upgrade --post-hook "service nginx start"
```

What could I be missing here?